# Accidentally removed /usr/share/applications

Tags: lubuntu, sudo

I'm really disappointed with myself, I was trying to remove a file and I did this. And now I can't see any of the applications in my Lubuntu desktop menu, even Xpad (for notes). I try and the programs still working. I delete them with sudo, any ideas of how I could recover something of my error?

I ran this command `sudo rm -rf /usr/share/applications`.

Thanks a lot.

[image: See my menu with no options]

Comment: make sure there is a /usr/share/applications directory & then reinstall all the apps whose .desktop file you've removed.

Comment: Hello @Doug, there is, the apps I would like to have again are the basic tools of the menu from lubuntu 16.04 like Xnote (notepad) the preferences and accesories... please help! The basic apps still working, I could execute them, but the icons are gone! all the icons of my menu

Comment: Even though all the apps still working, but all the icons are gone. All of them were in /usr/share/applications path, may be I could get a package or something?

Comment: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/applications`  & then for example   `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xpad`  Then do a sudo apt-get install --reinstall for all of your missing app .desktop files. Or do a  fresh install & don't use sudo haphazardly.

Comment: Thanks @doug I run your commands and with the help of Software Center of Ubuntu ( `sudo apt software-center` ), showing me the apps I have installed (but without Icon) I could reinstall all the defaults apps and those I have in addition. Solved my problem.

Comment: You should never use the `-r`-option when you want to remove a file, it's not necessary and nothing would have happened since `rm` will refuse to remove a non-empty directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The applications still work because they are not located in the `/usr/share/applicatons` folder.  That is the folder with the launchers of the applications.

One way to get the largest amount back is to install Ubuntu on a temporary space such as a Pen Drive, then copy the `/usr/share/applications` folder to your working install.

After that you will have all the default launchers.  You can restore the launchers for the missing ones by reinstalling the particular applications.  Use this command:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall [specific application]
```

Replace `[specific applications]` NOT including the bracket with the name of the application you want to restore to it's proper state.

Once you have the apps listed in a file you can use this cli (or a variation of) to automate the install:

```bash
$ for i in $(cat applications.list); do sudo apt install --reinstall -y $i;done
```

Comment: Thanks, like @doug recommends. I'll try to locate one-by-one the default applications installed with Software Center and reinstall each one of them with the above command.

Comment: You're very welcome, @LuigiLopez, I have a resent fresh install of 16.04.  There are 134 items in the `/usr/shared/applications folder`.  For your convenience  [this is the list](http://pastebin.com/X4RgkhLV).

Comment: He/she would want the default apps for Lubuntu, not Ubuntu..

Comment: @doug Thanks, Doug.  I guest that list would be a little smaller.  It was my intentions to give an idea of the amount of files that will have to be installed.  Maybe someone will provide a list of the Lubuntu specific launchers.  I was thinking that viewing the list might show that it might be hard to get all the launchers individually.  I have a Lubuntu installed, but it isn't recent and has lots of changes.  I may install Lubuntu and update the pastebin.

Comment: Thanks all of you, I used Software Center to guide me which apps I have and reinstalling them for get the Icon. Solved.

Comment: You could always run `dpkg -S /usr/share/applications` to get a list of packages that `dpkg` *thinks* should have files there - then reinstall those.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver this is the list of default apps for lubuntu [List](http://pastebin.com/s0WDCqTR)

Comment: @LuigiLopez I added a quick commandline to automate processing the installs, to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had mistakenly done the same but I figured how you can use a script to automate the applications installation.

The steps are

1. Create a script using your favorite editor. For example:

   ```
   nano reinstallApplications.sh
   ```
2. Copy the following code to the script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # Get a list of all installed packages
   installed_packages=$(dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}')

   # Reinstall each package using the package manager (apt in this case)
   for package in $installed_packages; do
       sudo apt-get install --reinstall --yes "$package"
   done
   ```
3. Make the script executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x reinstallApplications.sh
   ```
4. Run the script:

   ```
   ./reinstallApplications.sh
   ```